# Trying to get variable from another controller with respond_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, model-view-controller

I have a controller named `Orders`, and another one named `Customers`. So, on my `Order` I want to save who my `customer` is. These two models have associations.

So, in my new order view, I used one form to bring who the customer is by his "cpf" (cpf is a document that we use here in Brazil to identify citizens), and I did this:

```
<%= form_tag search_customer_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :cpf, params[:cpf], placeholder: 'CPF' %>
  <%= button_tag type: :submit, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
    <%= 'Selecionar' %>
  <% end%>
<% end%>
```

To make this `search_costumer_path` and make the `checkout_path` (that we'll use later on), i dit this to `routes.rb`:

```
get '/cart/checkout', to: 'orders#new', as: :checkout #-> This gives me the checkout_path
get 'search_customer', to: 'customers#search_customer'
```

And on my `customers_controller.rb` I did this:

```
def search_customer
  @customer = Customer.find_by!(cpf: params[:cpf])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to checkout_path } #-> @customer should be available in the checkout_path view, but it's not
  end
end
```

The problem is that when the app goes back to the `checkout_path`, `@customer` is `nil`.

Aditional information: To try to find the error, I replaced the `customers_controller`'s `search_customer` action to `byebug`, so I could handcode on the server to see if the params are passing and the variable is being set, and there I have no problem. I got something like this:

```
Input> params
Return> <ActionController::Parameters {"cpf"=>"05864899995", "button"=>"", "controller"=>"customers", "action"=>"search_customer"} permitted: false>
Input> @customer = Customer.find_by(cpf: params[:cpf])
Return> #<Customer id: 2, name: "Thiago Fiorese", cpf: "05864899995", cel_phone: "83984572906", email: "thiagofiorese@gmail.com", address: "Rua Helena Meira Lima", neighborhood: "Tambaú", city: "João Pessoa", state: "PB", zipcode: "58039081", complement: "Apto 1001", reference: "Ao lado do Motiva", created_at: "2020-01-20 19:36:16", updated_at: "2020-01-20 19:36:16", number: "691">
Input> @customer.name
Return: "Thiago Fiorese"
```

So... the params are passing, and the variable theoretically is being saved since I used the same code on my `search_customer` action. I'm guessing the problem is sending that variable back to the checkout page (orders controller) with the `respond_to`, since when I'm redirected back to `checkout_path`, the `@customer` is `nil`.

If you need this info: this app is a point-of-sale, so the user making the order is the shop owner or his employees, and the customer will not have access to the app, but should be saved on the order for statistics purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the @customer.id variable as a parameter like so:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to checkout_path(customer_id: @customer.id }
end
```

and then in your orders_controller

```
def new
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. Thank you very much for helping me out.